# Second router is hiding computers from each other

Tags: wireless-router

Until recently, I had 3 computers running off the same router. They were all configured to work on the same homegroup. Everything worked fine.

Now, to extend the wireless to another part of my house, I have put a second wireless router between the line from the first one and one of the other computers.

Now, that computer cannot see or be seen by the other 2 computers.

I assume it is basically creating a second or sub network and the 2 cannot communicate.

Is there a way to configure the second router so the computer beneath it can communicate with the other computers in the LAN?

Comment: Yes, they each have their own [subnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

Comment: Yes. Use the second wireless router as a WAP and not a router.

Answer (score 0):

Router model would be helpful.  Most new routers can be set into a Wireless Repeater mode that just extends the original network.  Also, the other router needs to be setup as a switch and not actually do any DHCP.  You are correct.  The second router has its own subnet, which the main router would not be able to see.